# Filling in Lookup columns with AD information SP2013

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, office-365, active-directory

Im trying to put together a simple contact list. Our Sharepoint Online is linked up to our Active directory. I was wondering if its possible to automate as much as possible to minimise errors on this contact list.

In my mind, it would be really useful to be able to have a person column that brings through the person but would it be possible to set up further columns such as mobile number & email address that populated with the information stored on AD?

Is this something that would be simple to do or am i way out of my depth? Im on a steep learning curve with Sharepoint so any help would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I do not think this is impossible, but you would need to make a Site feature for it using Visual Studios.  Have it create your list and your columns when activated.  You should be able to crawl to look up the user information using SPUserProfile Services. Then, create new columns with the information you get from each entry in your code.  Something like this should work for you.  Sounds good on paper anyways.

Here is a link that uses the JQuery API to find user profile information [here](http://www.vrdmn.com/2013/02/sharepoint-2013-working-with-user.html)